# Debian 8 - Circular dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, debian-jessie

A spinoff from my prior question here: [Installing Debian 8 packages & dependencies to a specified fs directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517019/installing-debian-8-packages-dependencies-to-a-specified-fs-directory)

From looking at the build-dependencies of various packages manually, I noticed there are quite a few circular dependencies throughout Debian 8 packages.

A simple one here:
https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/debhelper
https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/poa4

Integral source packages like glibc also have circular dependencies simply by virtue of how many packages that depend on it.

Out of curiosity, how does apt handle dependencies like this?  Does it install both simultaneously?  And if I were to try to dpkg them similarly, is there a command to do so?